# How to get wall clock time from xcode instruments time profiler?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

I am trying to profile a scenario in my iOS app, being able to see the CPU cycles spent per function. However I would like to check the wall clock time spent by the functions, as I am expecting some wait time because of resource contention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set "Record Waiting Threads" in the recording options (File > Recording Options). Then, when examining the call tree, you can use the Separate by State option in the Call Tree configuration pop-up.